# What are the definition of pecking order?

Tags: evolution, behaviour, literature, history, sociality

[Pecking order](https://ci.nii.ac.jp/naid/10029860251/) is the phenomenon that dominating individual usually eat first. It is commonly observed in animals. In animals, it is often due to the fact that the strong individual won the fights for eating first, or is able to win those fights in future.

This is what I used to learn: "a pecking order is about access to resources decided before the access as the result of a competition, not just straight competition". For example, the order of food-feeding in bird is sometimes decided by brightness of feathers, without any direct competition (fight) for the food.

**However**, many other sources equate pecking order with [dominance hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominance_hierarchy), or the metabolic evolutionary pressure, namingly some individuals have an evolutionary advantage over others, making them more fit to survive .

For example, bacteria can has dominance hierarchy (a.k.a pecking order). Supporting literature include [this](https://elifesciences.org/articles/65948).

See also [history of "pecking order"](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rstb.2020.0432), [pecking order of plants](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3565800?casa_token=MLC0K-tBT6kAAAAA%3A9lIEOTdsTb3LIOaH6xp_S79JBnPCJOA9GinhoOIGkF8ICvdUc1sTyQT0kc_Y7RIp4HuJXOLmm5WjKcSfQOY3bGR9ON1w_3TfC9sl6rddDR6CCpfAJnps4g&seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents), and [another article on dominance hierarchy](https://web.stanford.edu/group/stanfordbirds/text/uessays/uDominance_Hierarchies.html).

I am not sure if my understanding is correct and if this viewpoint is universally accepted -- is there a consensus on the definition of pecking order?

---

---

Comment: I think you have it wrong - a pecking order is about access to resources decided *before* the access as the result of a competition (usually strength, but not always, brighter feathers, bigger antennae can work for this), not just straight competition (being able to move faster). Voting to close for homework.

Comment: @bob1 How does this look like a homework? I get your point. I used to have the same viewpoint as yours but later I found that "pecking order" is equivalent to "dominance hierarchy" according to Wikipedia. I don't know who to trust. If you have one or two reliable reference I'll be appreciated!

Comment: It looks like homework because of these sections of the [homework](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) part in the help: "*A question that addresses a basic biology concept that may seem trivial to biology professionals*" and "*Include details of how you have attempted to form a solution. We will not do your homework assignments for you but we will point you in the right direction if you have made the effort to research the topic first.*"

Comment: @bob1 "Include details of how you have attempted to form a solution" makes a question good, not bad (or close-worthy). All questions are encouraged to include the attempts to solve the question.

Comment: But you don't show how you have attempted a solution - you've found a paper on bacterial competition, but you don't provide why you think this is appropriate to support your postulate, or any other evidence that you actually know what a pecking order is. Also your "pecking order" (1st) link is literally on peck strength in birds - nothing to do with pecking order at all. These together mean this is a low-effort homework post.

Comment: @bob1 I don't get your statement. First you said this question "looks like homework because the question include details of how I have attempted to form a solution"; then you said I did not attempt anything.

Comment: @bob1 Anyways, I must restate that this is clearly not a homework question. So it seems like that you have a different definition for "pecking order". May I again kindly ask your reference or sources? Most sources I found uses a similar definition to Wikipedia

Comment: No, what I said was that you need to provide details of how you have attempted to find a solution - read the link in my second comment. You haven't provided details. A pecking order is an informal hierarchical social dominance order where individuals higher in the order have more dominance or authority over those lower in the order. An example might be a family - Parents -> elder child -> younger child. A basic ecology or biology text will have a similar definition. This means again, homework as based on the "trivial for expert" part I quoted from the help page.

Comment: @bob1 You said that my first link is irrelevant to "pecking order". Could you please again provide reliable reference that Ebbe 1913 paper is irrelevant to pecking order?

Comment: My apologies I mis-read and looked at the citing paper, my Norwegian being somewhat lacking. However, I believe that the publication should be this one from 1921: Beiträge zur Biologie und Sozial- und Individualpsychologie bei Gallus domesticus (Contributions to the biology and social and individual psychology in Gallus domesticus) . Hønsenes stemme. Bidrag til hønsenes psykologi translates to "The voice of the chickens. Contribution to the psychology of chickens", which doesn't quite look right. However, I haven't been able to view the originals.

Comment: "Earliest" is a bit problematic; all species on Earth have been evolving for the exact same amount of time. In terms of generations, complex eukaryotes with long life spans have been evolving for a shorter time than many single-celled organisms.

Comment: @BryanKrause For example, the "earliest" language is created by Sumerian, according to many of the main stream anthropologists. In this question, the word “earliest” means the same thing. Maybe for biologists this word is a bit ambiguous. Of course, you are very welcome to suggest an alternative word or expression.

Comment: @HighGPA Well unless you expect to find this from the fossil record, the issue is that "earlier" things like Sumerian don't exist any more to be observed.

Comment: @BryanKrause Probably I should change the question to "approximately when did organisms evolved the property of pecking order?" Sometimes scientists and theoretically deduce an approximate time even before the actual evidence is discovered. Does this sounds better?